# Contact form 7 not submited with PHP version 7.2 and wordpress Version 5.3.1

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

We have PHP Version 7.2 and wordpress Version 5.3.1 and i have problem with submitting Contact form 7.
i have also check plugin conflict but everything is fine.
i filling everything perfect in contact form 7.

Comment: Please put some error here .. so developers understand what's the problem

Comment: There was an error trying to send your message. please try again later.

Comment: Are you working in local or live?

Comment: working on live

Comment: Its email related error, Contact form are not able to send the emails for your contact inquiry so please check the email are working or not

Comment: Email is working fine for other form my site is on aws server ec2

Answer (score 0):

Probably it cannot send email. You can either be sure you can send email through your server and email client working correctly. If not you can try plugins that sends email via SMTP.

You can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/ this plugin for example. You can open an email account enter smtp details on plugins page. After that you can test that you can send email it should work fine.

Comment: I have install this plugin on local it give following error.

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting


I have use 
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
Type of Encryption: SSL
SMTP Port: 465
SMTP Authentication: YES
SMTP Username: myuser@gmail.com
SMTP Password: 12324234

I have also tried with TLS with port  587

Comment: When i downgrade PHP Version from 7.2 to 5.6 on local it working fine.
With php 7 contact form not working

Answer (score 0):

Use another contact plugin and check after submit its working or not.